# WPF Bound Editable Combobox not changing ID on Text Change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm no sure what the right way to `bind` the `combobox control` is to my `view model`.

I'm using a MVVM approach so in my `viewmodel` i'm loading all the `CDType` data and am binding their source in combination with the actual record properties `model.CDType.id` and `model.CDType.name`.

**What happens is that when i change the text?** - i keep my old id (from the load routine) and get a new text value from the combobox binding therefor always writing over the existing record instead of creating a new one.

How can i make my combobox set the id to 0 / undefined if the text isn't in the list? (manually? - kind of lame)

Anything will help - thanks!

**TL;DR:** Editable Combo-box not updating ID on text change.

Sample Xaml binding:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlCDType"    
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"    
          TextSearch.TextPath="Name"     
          ItemsSource="{Binding CDTypes}"    
          SelectedValue="{Binding Assignment.CDType.ID}"     
          Text="{Binding Assignment.CDType.Name,     
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,    
          NotifyOnValidationError=True,     
          ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"      
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"     
          SelectedValuePath="ID"     
          IsEditable="True"     
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"     
          Margin="98,10,0,0"     
          VerticalAlignment="Top"     
          Width="136" />
```

Comment: unclear ! it looks like you are trying to create a new Id by typing in CBox.

Comment: Keep it simple.  `ItemsSource` should be instances of a type.  `SelectedValue` should be a single instance from among those bound to `ItemsSource`. Both should be bound to your view model.  Trying to bind to subproperties of a model in this scenario or do anything else weird is only going to lead to heartbreak and sorrow.  If you must, wrap your models in a simplified version that promotes subproperties to the surface.  But definitely stay away from that `Binding Assignment.CDType.ID` nonsense.

Comment: @will i'll get back to you once i've changed this around to fit your comment - thanks. (pre-code issues: Not understanding - CDTypes is a Class with the 2 properties in it - to fill the combobox. Assignment.CDType.ID is the Model I've loaded from my DB holding the currently saved value. How is that wrong?)

Comment: 'Wrong' is subjective, but in this case Easy is objective.  ItemsControls are designed to work with instances and uses Object.Equals to determine which item in ItemsSource is in SelectedValue (if they're not structs; this is just a comment, so I'm cutting out detail).  You can do all kinds of different things in order to get selection working with your design, *but you're only making things hard on yourself*.  Don't make things hard on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

as I can understand you need update the previous last selected value when the name of selected ComboBox item is changed manually and this name is not presented in the ComboBox ItemSource. Here is my suggestion, it is combination of your ComboBox control data binding and logic defined in the ViewModel.

**Explanation of binding**

1. Since the ComboBox ItemsSource is the collection of Cd (the collection of ComboModels), thus the `TextSearch.TextPath` binding should be defined as CDType.Name where the  CdType is property defined in the ComboModel that describes the sub-model, and the Name is an actual search path which is describing the sub-model.
2. The ComboBox Text property is binded to AssignmentText property to trigger the updating logic when the combo is lost the focus (as defined in binding).
3. The ItemsSource is trivial as defined in your sample code.
4. Selected value will bring a whole model to update (in case we change the selected value name).
5. Since the ComboBox ItemsSource is the collection of Cd (let's call this ComboModel) the `DisplayMemberPath` binding should be defined as CDType.Name where the  CdType is property defined in the ComboModel that describes the sub-model, and the Name is an actual search path which is describing the sub-model.

**Xaml Code:**

```
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <comboBoxWhenNoAnySelectedHelpAttempt:ComboboxDataContext/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ddlCDType"    
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
                      IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
                      StaysOpenOnEdit="True"    
                      TextSearch.TextPath="CDType.Name"
                      Text="{Binding AssignmentText,     
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay,
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CDTypes}"    
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Assignment}"     
                      DisplayMemberPath="CDType.Name"     
                      IsEditable="True"     
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"     
                      Margin="98,10,0,0"     
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"     
                      Width="136" />
            <!--added to see changes in updated combo box item-->
            <TextBlock >
                      <Run Text="Name:"/>
                      <Run Text="{Binding Assignment.CDType.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
                      <Run Text="Id:"/>
                      <Run Text="{Binding Assignment.CDType.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**VM code**

```
public class ComboboxDataContext:BaseObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<ComboModel> _cdTypes;
    private ComboModel _assignment;
    private string _assignmentText;
    private string _lastAcceptedName;


    public ComboboxDataContext()
    {
        CDTypes = new ObservableCollection<ComboModel>
        {
            new ComboModel
            {
                CDType = new ComboModelSubModel
                {
                    Name = "Cd-1",
                    ID = "1",
                },
            },
            new ComboModel
            {
                CDType = new ComboModelSubModel
                {
                    Name = "Cd-2",
                    ID = "2",
                }
            },
            new ComboModel
            {
                CDType = new ComboModelSubModel
                {
                    Name = "Cd-3",
                    ID = "3",
                },
            },
            new ComboModel
            {
                CDType = new ComboModelSubModel
                {
                    Name = "Cd-4",
                    ID = "4",
                }
            }
        };
        Assignment = CDTypes.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ComboModel> CDTypes
    {
        get { return _cdTypes; }
        set
        {
            _cdTypes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ComboModel Assignment
    {
        get { return _assignment; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _lastAcceptedName = _assignment.CDType.Name;
            _assignment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //on lost focus when edit is done will check and update the last edited value
    public string AssignmentText
    {
        get { return _assignmentText; }
        set
        {
            _assignmentText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            UpDateSourceCollection(AssignmentText);
        }
    }

    //will do the the update on combo lost focus to prevent the 
    //annessasary updates (each property change will make a lot of noice in combo)
    private void UpDateSourceCollection(string assignmentText)
    {
        var existingModel = CDTypes.FirstOrDefault(model => model.CDType.Name == assignmentText);
        if (existingModel != null) return;
        if (_lastAcceptedName == null)
        {
            CDTypes.Add(new ComboModel{CDType = new ComboModelSubModel{ID = string.Empty, Name = assignmentText}});
        }
        else
        {
            var existingModelToEdit = CDTypes.FirstOrDefault(model => model.CDType.Name == _lastAcceptedName);
            if(existingModelToEdit == null) return;
            existingModelToEdit.CDType.Name = assignmentText;
            existingModelToEdit.CDType.ID = string.Empty;
        }

    }
}

public class ComboModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private ComboModelSubModel _cdType;

    public ComboModelSubModel CDType
    {
        get { return _cdType; }
        set
        {
            _cdType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ComboModelSubModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseObservableObject code**

```
    /// <summary>`enter code here`
/// implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (.net 4.5)
/// </summary>
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Interesting - so basically the combobox when editable, when adding new text doesn't automatically know its not part of the collection and therefor keeps the assigned value (id) in memory and attaches the new text instead of updating it to a (0/string.Empty()) - therefor forcing us to handle it manually?

Thanks for the answer I'll implement this later today!